# Object of same type as class

Tags: c++, object

In c++ how do I have an object as the same type as its containing class eg:

```
class Test
{
public:

private:
  Test t;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, you can't.

You can have a pointer to an object of the same type, but not an object itself.

If you NEED to do this (i.e.) can't use a pointer, your design is probably wrong. If you can use a pointer, use it.

**Some reasons:**

You'd have to create the object on instantiation, that means an infinite recursive call on the constructor.

What would the `sizeof()` for the object be?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, since it would require infinite recursion. (Your `t` would contain another `t`, so you'd have `t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t....` ad infinitum). What you could do though is put a pointer to another object inside, e.g.

```
private:
   Test *t;
```

The problem is that when you write:

```
Test t;
```

The compiler *needs* to know the size of `Test` in order to provide sufficient storage. At the point where you wrote `Test t;` that size isn't known because the compiler hasn't seen the end of the definition of `Test` (i.e. the `;` after the closing `}`) and thus can't determine the size of it.

Answer (score 1):

That's **not possible**. At the max you can have a **reference or pointer** of the same 
`class` within it.

```
class Test
{
private:
  Test *t;
};
```

As a side note, `static` objects are allowed. This is because, they are not actually bound with any particular instance of `class` object. i.e.:

```
class Test
{
private:
  Test t; // error
  static Test st; // ok!
};  // define 'st' in the translation unit
```